# How to convert variables given by user into numbers

Tags: python, string, integer, converters

Having the following code below

```
steak = 40.00
pepsi = 3.45
order1 = input("What would you like to have?")
order2 = input("What would you like to have?")
total = order1 + order2
```

How would I convert `order1` and `order2` into numbers so they can be added depending on what the user chooses to have?

Comment: What do you mean? this: `total = int(order1) + int(order2)` or `total = float(order1) + float(order2)`?

Comment: @Rooney Program for what? Its not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Is it like a homework assignment where you have to use the code above or can you change it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to add up the prices of the items the user chose to buy.

```
products = {'steak':40.00, 'pepsi':3.45}
order1 = input("What would you like to have? ")
order2 = input("What would you like to have? ")
total = products.get(order1) + products.get(order2)
print(total)
```

This prints `43.45` given orders of `steak` and `pepsi`. You can do further calculations (tax, tip, change, etc.) as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but this is probably the simplest way:

```
x = raw_input("What would you like to eat? ")
if x == "Steak":
    price1 = 40
else:
    print "Sorry we only have steak!"

y = raw_input("What would you like to drink? ")
if y == "Pepsi":
    price2 = 3.45
else:
    print "Sorry but we only have Pepsi!"

total = price1 + price2

print total
```

Comment: Note that choosing a drink of `Pepsi` would fail, even though the user has been told that it is available. I'd recommend `if y.lower() == 'pepsi'`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks, I just changed the Pepsi to capital P.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I wrote Pepsi with lower case because the original post was lower case, Now I changed the steak to Steak too. In any case, as long as the logic is understood, it should be ok.